# Clear selected range picker in vue-rangedate-picker (Vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wanted to clear the selected dates in my <VueRangedatePicker @selected="updateDatePicker"> by clicking the clear button. however when i do that. the data is null already but the display its not clearing the selected value. can someone help me? Thank you

You can access the code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-sky-3uwch?file=/src/App.vue:0-966

This is the code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <VueRangedatePicker @selected="updateDatePicker"></VueRangedatePicker>
    <button class="button" @click="cleardata()">Clear</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueRangedatePicker from "vue-rangedate-picker";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueRangedatePicker,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      datepicker: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    cleardata() {
      this.datepicker = null;
    },
    updateDatePicker(value) {
      console.log("updating datepicker value");
      this.datepicker = value;

      console.log("DATE PICKER", this.datepicker);
      console.log("start: " + this.datepicker.start);
      console.log("end: " + this.datepicker.end);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u need to null the 2 date because u are using date range

```
cleardata() {
      this.datepicker.start = null;
      this.datepicker.end = null;
},
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: I added the code and removed the image thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use "ref" to access the component function "clickRange":

```
<template>
    ...
    <date-range-picker ref="datePicker"...
```

```
this.$refs.datePicker.clickRange(0)
```

If you are using TS:

```
interface DatePicker extends Vue {
    clickRange: Function;
}
```

```
(this.$refs.datePicker as DatePicker).clickRange(0)
```